# How to excecute asyncronous promise used Promise.All()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to ask, how do you run ascyronus promises in the promise all? when I run the function that I made Promise.all runs all the functions in parallel (syncronus)

if you run the code below then the result is

```
// jon
// andrey
// tania
// JON
// ANDREY
// TANIA
```

here is my code

```
// First promise returns an array
const getUsers = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve([{ id: 'jon' }, { id: 'andrey' }, { id: 'tania' }]), 600)
  })
}

// Second promise relies on the resulting array of first promise
const getIdFromUser = users => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve(users.id), 500)
  })
}

// Third promise relies on the result of the second promise
const capitalizeIds = id => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve(id.toUpperCase()), 200)
  })
}

const newPromise = async user => {
      const userId = await getIdFromUser(user)
      console.log(userId) //jon
      const capitalizedId = await capitalizeIds(userId)
      console.log(capitalizedId) //JON
      return
  }

const runAsyncFunctions = async () => {
  const users = await getUsers()
  
  await  Promise.all(users.map(user => newPromise(user)))
}

runAsyncFunctions()
```

but I want the results as below, this will work if the promise all is run asyncronus

```
// jon
// JON
// andrey
// ANDREY
// tania
// TANIA
```

and this is my playground code [playground](https://replit.com/@ilhamstomdevva/CalculatingAwfulComputerscience)

Comment: You probably should create a chain for promises and then set them resolving in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to initialize a Promise only after the last Promise has finished - that is, run them in *serial*, not in parallel - then `.map` and `Promise.all` is not the right tool for the job, because that'll initialize all Promises at once. `await` in a `for` loop instead:

```
const runAsyncFunctions = async() => {
  const users = await getUsers()
  for (const user of users) {
    await newPromise(user);
  }
}
```

```js
// First promise returns an array
const getUsers = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve([{
      id: 'jon'
    }, {
      id: 'andrey'
    }, {
      id: 'tania'
    }]), 600)
  })
}

// Second promise relies on the resulting array of first promise
const getIdFromUser = users => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve(users.id), 500)
  })
}

// Third promise relies on the result of the second promise
const capitalizeIds = id => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve(id.toUpperCase()), 200)
  })
}

const newPromise = async user => {
  const userId = await getIdFromUser(user)
  console.log(userId) //jon
  const capitalizedId = await capitalizeIds(userId)
  console.log(capitalizedId) //JON
  return
}

const runAsyncFunctions = async() => {
  const users = await getUsers()
  for (const user of users) {
    await newPromise(user);
  }
}

runAsyncFunctions()
```

If your real code allows you to do the logging *outside*, you can keep running the Promises in parallel, but only log the results in order once they're all completed:

```
const newPromise = async user => {
  const userId = await getIdFromUser(user)
  const capitalizedId = await capitalizeIds(userId)
  return [userId, capitalizedId];
}
const runAsyncFunctions = async() => {
  const users = await getUsers()

  const names = await Promise.all(users.map(user => newPromise(user)));
  for (const name of names.flat()) {
    console.log(name);
  }
}
```

```js
// First promise returns an array
const getUsers = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve([{
      id: 'jon'
    }, {
      id: 'andrey'
    }, {
      id: 'tania'
    }]), 600)
  })
}

// Second promise relies on the resulting array of first promise
const getIdFromUser = users => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve(users.id), 500)
  })
}

// Third promise relies on the result of the second promise
const capitalizeIds = id => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve(id.toUpperCase()), 200)
  })
}

const newPromise = async user => {
  const userId = await getIdFromUser(user)
  const capitalizedId = await capitalizeIds(userId)
  return [userId, capitalizedId];
}

const runAsyncFunctions = async() => {
  const users = await getUsers()

  const names = await Promise.all(users.map(user => newPromise(user)));
  for (const name of names.flat()) {
    console.log(name);
  }
}

runAsyncFunctions()
```

Answer (score 2):

Promise all runs like a funny wrapper around a normal array interator function...

```js
let results = Promise.all(myarray.map(item => {
  try {
    return await functionThatReturnsAPromise()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return null
  }
}))
```

A good alternative to Promise all is for of because you can put await on it...

```js
for await (let item of myarray) {
  // Try catch etc
}
```

Node will be fine with this, but you might want to check browser support if you're running it in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

the getIdFromUser is executed async. This means on the next line, the whole array  is already there and that is why it is printed in a serial manner. Fetching both the userId and the capitalized firstly will result in what you want

```
// First promise returns an array
const getUsers = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve([{ id: 'jon' }, { id: 'andrey' }, { id: 'tania' }]), 600)
  })
}

// Second promise relies on the resulting array of first promise
const getIdFromUser = async users => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve(users.id), 0)
  })
}

// Third promise relies on the result of the second promise
const capitalizeIds = id => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve(id.toUpperCase()), 0)
  })
}

const newPromise = async user => {
      const userId = await getIdFromUser(user)
      const capitalizedId = await capitalizeIds(userId)
      console.log(userId) //jon
      console.log(capitalizedId) //JON
      return
  }

const runAsyncFunctions = async () => {
  const users = await getUsers()
  console.log(users)
  await  Promise.all(users.map(user => newPromise(user)))
}

runAsyncFunctions()
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but in the actual case I want to run "console.log (userId) // jon" before "await capitalizedId"

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make it simple and removed functions that are not required, I can prodcue the requested output in question
You can alos check here [solution](https://repl.it/repls/StainedThosePipelining)

```
  // First promise returns an array
const getUsers = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return setTimeout(() => resolve([{ id: 'jon' }, { id: 'andrey' }, { id: 'tania' }]), 600)
    })
}

// Second promise relies on the resulting array of first promise
const getIdFromUser = users => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return setTimeout(() => resolve(users.id), 500)
    })
}

// You do not need this, why make it complicated ??
// Third promise relies on the result of the second promise
// const capitalizeIds = async id => {
//     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//         return setTimeout(() => resolve(id.toUpperCase()), 200)
//     })
// }

function capitalizeIds(id)
{
    return  id.toUpperCase();
}
const runAsyncFunctions = async () => {
    const users = await getUsers()

     users.map(user => {
        console.log(user.id) //jon
        const capitalizedId = capitalizeIds(user.id);
        console.log(capitalizedId) //JON
    })
}

runAsyncFunctions()
```

Comment: thank you the code is cleaner,
but I need to solve it using "promised". the code above is just an example.